# Delete a string using replace keyword

Tags: c#, replace

I have a problem with `String.Replace` method. It is not working for buttonclick events.

i use this code

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       textBox3.Text.Replace("apple","");
}
```

[image: Please see the image]

When I press clear button it doesn't remove "apple" words

Comment: `testBox3.Text =  textBox3.Text.Replace("apple","");` simple fix would have been to read up on the string.Replace() function

Comment: It is well knows fact that [C# string replace does not work](https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+string+replace+does+not+work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replace function does not change the control, it returns a new string.

If textBox3 says "applebananacherry"

```
String text = textBox3.Text.Replace("apple","");
```

would leave text with "bananacherry"

What you need is

```
textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text.Replace("apple", "");
```

Comment: i need to remove apple word from textbox3 when i click clear button

Comment: how to delete one apple words from many apple words are include text

Comment: If you only want to remove the first apple:

            int index = textBox3.Text.IndexOf("apple");
            if (index > -1)
                textBox3.Text = s.Remove(index, "apple".Length);